# mysql 8 only creating single log file instead of 2 (ib_logfile0)

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql8, innodb-log-file-size

I am having an issue with one of my mysql servers that has to do with the innodb logfiles. Even though it is configured to have 2 logfiles as normal, when I start up the server it only creates one of them. This causes a big issue as if the service is restarted for any reason it will fail to start up as it does not find what it is expecting with the log files. renaming the old ib_logfile0 will allow it to boot up again.

I am afraid of any type of data corruption at this point. The server currently has version:
`/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

I have attached the configuration below (stripped for length) dumped from the running instance. Thank you!

```
abort-slave-event-count                                      0
activate-all-roles-on-login                                  FALSE
archive                                                      ON
autocommit                                                   TRUE
automatic-sp-privileges                                      TRUE
avoid-temporal-upgrade                                       FALSE
back-log                                                     151
basedir                                                      /usr/
big-tables                                                   FALSE
binlog-cache-size                                            32768
binlog-checksum                                              CRC32
binlog-direct-non-transactional-updates                      FALSE
binlog-encryption                                            FALSE
binlog-error-action                                          ABORT_SERVER
binlog-expire-logs-seconds                                   259200
binlog-format                                                ROW
binlog-group-commit-sync-delay                               0
binlog-group-commit-sync-no-delay-count                      0
binlog-gtid-simple-recovery                                  TRUE
binlog-max-flush-queue-time                                  0
binlog-order-commits                                         TRUE
binlog-rotate-encryption-master-key-at-startup               FALSE
binlog-row-event-max-size                                    8192
binlog-row-image                                             FULL
binlog-row-metadata                                          MINIMAL
binlog-row-value-options                                     
binlog-rows-query-log-events                                 FALSE
binlog-stmt-cache-size                                       32768
binlog-transaction-dependency-history-size                   25000
binlog-transaction-dependency-tracking                       COMMIT_ORDER
bulk-insert-buffer-size                                      8388608
collation-server                                             utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
completion-type                                              NO_CHAIN
concurrent-insert                                            AUTO
connect-timeout                                              10
console                                                      FALSE
create-admin-listener-thread                                 FALSE
cte-max-recursion-depth                                      1000
daemonize                                                    FALSE
datadir                                                      /var/lib/mysql/
default-storage-engine                                       InnoDB
default-table-encryption                                     FALSE
default-tmp-storage-engine                                   InnoDB
delay-key-write                                              ON
delayed-insert-limit                                         100
delayed-insert-timeout                                       300
delayed-queue-size                                           1000
div-precision-increment                                      4
end-markers-in-json                                          FALSE
enforce-gtid-consistency                                     FALSE
eq-range-index-dive-limit                                    200
event-scheduler                                              ON
expire-logs-days                                             0
explicit-defaults-for-timestamp                              TRUE
external-locking                                             FALSE
flush                                                        FALSE
flush-time                                                   0
gdb                                                          FALSE
general-log                                                  FALSE
gtid-executed-compression-period                             1000
gtid-mode                                                    OFF
help                                                         TRUE
histogram-generation-max-mem-size                            20000000
host-cache-size                                              279
information-schema-stats-expiry                              86400
init-connect                                                 
init-file                                                    (No default value)
initialize                                                   FALSE
initialize-insecure                                          FALSE
innodb-adaptive-flushing                                     TRUE
innodb-adaptive-flushing-lwm                                 10
innodb-adaptive-hash-index                                   TRUE
innodb-adaptive-hash-index-parts                             8
innodb-adaptive-max-sleep-delay                              150000
innodb-api-bk-commit-interval                                5
innodb-api-disable-rowlock                                   FALSE
innodb-api-enable-binlog                                     FALSE
innodb-api-enable-mdl                                        FALSE
innodb-api-trx-level                                         0
innodb-autoextend-increment                                  64
innodb-autoinc-lock-mode                                     2
innodb-buffer-pool-chunk-size                                134217728
innodb-buffer-pool-dump-at-shutdown                          TRUE
innodb-buffer-pool-dump-now                                  FALSE
innodb-buffer-pool-dump-pct                                  25
innodb-buffer-pool-filename                                  ib_buffer_pool
innodb-buffer-pool-in-core-file                              TRUE
innodb-buffer-pool-instances                                 0
innodb-buffer-pool-load-abort                                FALSE
innodb-buffer-pool-load-at-startup                           TRUE
innodb-buffer-pool-load-now                                  FALSE
innodb-buffer-pool-size                                      134217728
innodb-change-buffer-max-size                                25
innodb-change-buffering                                      all
innodb-checksum-algorithm                                    crc32
innodb-cmp-per-index-enabled                                 FALSE
innodb-commit-concurrency                                    0
innodb-compression-failure-threshold-pct                     5
innodb-compression-level                                     6
innodb-compression-pad-pct-max                               50
innodb-concurrency-tickets                                   5000
innodb-data-file-path                                        ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb-data-home-dir                                         (No default value)
innodb-deadlock-detect                                       TRUE
innodb-dedicated-server                                      TRUE
innodb-default-row-format                                    dynamic
innodb-directories                                           (No default value)
innodb-disable-sort-file-cache                               FALSE
innodb-doublewrite                                           TRUE
innodb-fast-shutdown                                         1
innodb-file-per-table                                        TRUE
innodb-fill-factor                                           100
innodb-flush-log-at-timeout                                  1
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit                               2
innodb-flush-method                                          fsync
innodb-flush-neighbors                                       0
innodb-flush-sync                                            TRUE
innodb-flushing-avg-loops                                    30
innodb-force-load-corrupted                                  FALSE
innodb-force-recovery                                        0
innodb-fsync-threshold                                       0
innodb-ft-aux-table                                          (No default value)
innodb-ft-cache-size                                         8000000
innodb-ft-enable-diag-print                                  FALSE
innodb-ft-enable-stopword                                    TRUE
innodb-ft-max-token-size                                     84
innodb-ft-min-token-size                                     3
innodb-ft-num-word-optimize                                  2000
innodb-ft-result-cache-limit                                 2000000000
innodb-ft-server-stopword-table                              (No default value)
innodb-ft-sort-pll-degree                                    2
innodb-ft-total-cache-size                                   640000000
innodb-ft-user-stopword-table                                (No default value)
innodb-idle-flush-pct                                        100
innodb-io-capacity                                           200
innodb-io-capacity-max                                       18446744073709551615
innodb-lock-wait-timeout                                     50
innodb-log-buffer-size                                       16777216
innodb-log-checksums                                         TRUE
innodb-log-compressed-pages                                  TRUE
innodb-log-file-size                                         67108864
innodb-log-files-in-group                                    2
innodb-log-group-home-dir                                    (No default value)
innodb-log-spin-cpu-abs-lwm                                  80
innodb-log-spin-cpu-pct-hwm                                  50
innodb-log-wait-for-flush-spin-hwm                           400
innodb-log-write-ahead-size                                  8192
innodb-lru-scan-depth                                        1024
innodb-max-dirty-pages-pct                                   90
innodb-max-dirty-pages-pct-lwm                               10
innodb-max-purge-lag                                         0
innodb-max-purge-lag-delay                                   0
innodb-max-undo-log-size                                     1073741824
innodb-monitor-disable                                       (No default value)
innodb-monitor-enable                                        (No default value)
innodb-monitor-reset                                         (No default value)
innodb-monitor-reset-all                                     (No default value)
innodb-numa-interleave                                       FALSE
innodb-old-blocks-pct                                        37
innodb-old-blocks-time                                       1000
innodb-online-alter-log-max-size                             134217728
innodb-open-files                                            0
innodb-optimize-fulltext-only                                FALSE
innodb-page-cleaners                                         4
innodb-page-size                                             16384
innodb-parallel-read-threads                                 4
innodb-print-all-deadlocks                                   FALSE
innodb-print-ddl-logs                                        FALSE
innodb-purge-batch-size                                      300
innodb-purge-rseg-truncate-frequency                         128
innodb-purge-threads                                         4
innodb-random-read-ahead                                     FALSE
innodb-read-ahead-threshold                                  56
innodb-read-io-threads                                       4
innodb-read-only                                             FALSE
innodb-redo-log-archive-dirs                                 (No default value)
innodb-redo-log-encrypt                                      FALSE
innodb-replication-delay                                     0
innodb-rollback-on-timeout                                   FALSE
innodb-rollback-segments                                     128
innodb-sort-buffer-size                                      1048576
innodb-spin-wait-delay                                       6
innodb-spin-wait-pause-multiplier                            50
innodb-stats-auto-recalc                                     TRUE
innodb-stats-include-delete-marked                           FALSE
innodb-stats-method                                          nulls_equal
innodb-stats-on-metadata                                     FALSE
innodb-stats-persistent                                      TRUE
innodb-stats-persistent-sample-pages                         20
innodb-stats-transient-sample-pages                          8
innodb-status-file                                           FALSE
innodb-status-output                                         FALSE
innodb-status-output-locks                                   FALSE
innodb-strict-mode                                           TRUE
innodb-sync-array-size                                       1
innodb-sync-spin-loops                                       30
innodb-table-locks                                           TRUE
innodb-temp-data-file-path                                   ibtmp1:12M:autoextend
innodb-temp-tablespaces-dir                                  (No default value)
innodb-thread-concurrency                                    0
innodb-thread-sleep-delay                                    10000
innodb-tmpdir                                                (No default value)
innodb-undo-directory                                        (No default value)
innodb-undo-log-encrypt                                      FALSE
innodb-undo-log-truncate                                     TRUE
innodb-undo-tablespaces                                      2
innodb-use-native-aio                                        TRUE
innodb-write-io-threads                                      4
internal-tmp-mem-storage-engine                              TempTable
join-buffer-size                                             262144
keep-files-on-create                                         FALSE
key-buffer-size                                              8388608
key-cache-age-threshold                                      300
key-cache-block-size                                         1024
key-cache-division-limit                                     100
language                                                     /usr/share/mysql-8.0/
large-pages                                                  FALSE
lc-messages                                                  en_US
lc-messages-dir                                              /usr/share/mysql-8.0/
lc-time-names                                                en_US
local-infile                                                 FALSE
lock-wait-timeout                                            31536000
log-bin                                                      binlog
log-bin-index                                                binlog.index
log-bin-trust-function-creators                              FALSE
log-bin-use-v1-row-events                                    FALSE
log-error                                                    stderr
log-error-services                                           log_filter_internal; log_sink_internal
log-error-suppression-list                                   
log-error-verbosity                                          1
log-isam                                                     myisam.log
log-output                                                   FILE
log-queries-not-using-indexes                                FALSE
log-raw                                                      FALSE
log-short-format                                             FALSE
log-slave-updates                                            TRUE
log-slow-admin-statements                                    FALSE
log-slow-extra                                               FALSE
log-slow-slave-statements                                    FALSE
log-statements-unsafe-for-binlog                             TRUE
log-tc                                                       tc.log
log-tc-size                                                  24576
log-throttle-queries-not-using-indexes                       0
log-timestamps                                               UTC
long-query-time                                              10
low-priority-updates                                         FALSE
lower-case-table-names                                       0
mandatory-roles                                              
master-info-file                                             master.info
master-info-repository                                       TABLE
master-retry-count                                           86400
master-verify-checksum                                       FALSE
max-allowed-packet                                           67108864
max-binlog-cache-size                                        18446744073709547520
max-binlog-dump-events                                       0
max-binlog-size                                              1073741824
max-binlog-stmt-cache-size                                   18446744073709547520
max-connect-errors                                           100
max-connections                                              151
max-delayed-threads                                          20
max-digest-length                                            1024
max-error-count                                              1024
max-execution-time                                           0
max-heap-table-size                                          16777216
max-join-size                                                18446744073709551615
max-length-for-sort-data                                     4096
max-points-in-geometry                                       65536
max-prepared-stmt-count                                      16382
max-relay-log-size                                           0
max-seeks-for-key                                            18446744073709551615
max-sort-length                                              1024
max-write-lock-count                                         18446744073709551615
memlock                                                      FALSE
min-examined-row-limit                                       0
myisam-block-size                                            1024
myisam-data-pointer-size                                     6
myisam-max-sort-file-size                                    9223372036853727232
myisam-mmap-size                                             18446744073709551615
myisam-recover-options                                       OFF
myisam-repair-threads                                        1
myisam-sort-buffer-size                                      8388608
myisam-stats-method                                          nulls_unequal
myisam-use-mmap                                              FALSE
mysql-native-password-proxy-users                            FALSE
mysqlx                                                       ON
mysqlx-cache-cleaner                                         ON
mysqlx-compression-algorithms                                DEFLATE_STREAM,LZ4_MESSAGE,ZSTD_STREAM
mysqlx-connect-timeout                                       30
mysqlx-document-id-unique-prefix                             0
mysqlx-enable-hello-notice                                   TRUE
mysqlx-idle-worker-thread-timeout                            60
mysqlx-interactive-timeout                                   28800
mysqlx-max-allowed-packet                                    67108864
mysqlx-max-connections                                       100
mysqlx-min-worker-threads                                    2
mysqlx-port                                                  33060
mysqlx-port-open-timeout                                     0
mysqlx-read-timeout                                          30
mysqlx-socket                                                (No default value)
mysqlx-wait-timeout                                          28800
mysqlx-write-timeout                                         60
net-buffer-length                                            16384
net-read-timeout                                             30
net-retry-count                                              10
net-write-timeout                                            60
new                                                          FALSE
ngram                                                        ON
ngram-token-size                                             2
old                                                          FALSE
old-alter-table                                              FALSE
old-style-user-limits                                        FALSE
open-files-limit                                             8161
pid-file                                                     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
plugin-dir                                                   /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/
preload-buffer-size                                          32768
profiling-history-size                                       15
query-alloc-block-size                                       8192
query-prealloc-size                                          8192
range-alloc-block-size                                       4096
range-optimizer-max-mem-size                                 8388608
read-buffer-size                                             131072
read-only                                                    FALSE
read-rnd-buffer-size                                         262144
regexp-stack-limit                                           8000000
regexp-time-limit                                            32
require-secure-transport                                     FALSE
rpl-read-size                                                8192
rpl-stop-slave-timeout                                       31536000
safe-user-create                                             FALSE
schema-definition-cache                                      256
secondary-engine-cost-threshold                              100000
secure-file-priv                                             /var/lib/mysql-files
server-id                                                    1
server-id-bits                                               32
session-track-transaction-info                               OFF
show-create-table-verbosity                                  FALSE
show-old-temporals                                           FALSE
show-slave-auth-info                                         FALSE
skip-grant-tables                                            FALSE
skip-name-resolve                                            FALSE
skip-networking                                              FALSE
skip-show-database                                           FALSE
skip-slave-start                                             FALSE
slow-launch-time                                             2
socket                                                       /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sort-buffer-size                                             262144
sporadic-binlog-dump-fail                                    FALSE
sql-mode                                                     ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
sql-require-primary-key                                      FALSE
stored-program-cache                                         256
stored-program-definition-cache                              256
super-large-pages                                            FALSE
super-read-only                                              FALSE
symbolic-links                                               FALSE
sync-binlog                                                  1
sync-master-info                                             10000
sync-relay-log                                               10000
sync-relay-log-info                                          10000
sysdate-is-now                                               FALSE
table-definition-cache                                       2000
table-encryption-privilege-check                             FALSE
table-open-cache                                             4000
table-open-cache-instances                                   16
tablespace-definition-cache                                  256
tc-heuristic-recover                                         OFF
temptable-max-ram                                            1073741824
temptable-use-mmap                                           TRUE
thread-cache-size                                            9
thread-handling                                              one-thread-per-connection
thread-stack                                                 286720
tmp-table-size                                               16777216
tmpdir                                                       /tmp
transaction-alloc-block-size                                 8192
transaction-isolation                                        REPEATABLE-READ
transaction-prealloc-size                                    4096
updatable-views-with-limit                                   YES
upgrade                                                      AUTO
validate-config                                              FALSE
windowing-use-high-precision                                 TRUE
```

Error log:

````
2020-03-04T12:22:44.645032Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 1642
2020-03-04T12:22:44.688308Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012360] [InnoDB]  Option innodb_dedicated_server is ignored for innodb_log_file_size because innodb_log_file_size=67108864 is specified explicitly.
2020-03-04T12:22:45.087351Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012961] [InnoDB] Only one log file found
2020-03-04T12:22:45.087663Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error not found.
2020-03-04T12:22:45.578090Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2020-03-04T12:22:45.578608Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-03-04T12:22:45.579056Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-03-04T12:22:45.584321Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-03-04T12:23:42.214245Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 1851
2020-03-04T12:23:42.234222Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012360] [InnoDB]  Option innodb_dedicated_server is ignored for innodb_log_file_size because innodb_log_file_size=67108864 is specified explicitly.
2020-03-04T12:23:42.458195Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012961] [InnoDB] Only one log file found
2020-03-04T12:23:42.458462Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error not found.
2020-03-04T12:23:42.952511Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2020-03-04T12:23:42.953093Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-03-04T12:23:42.953603Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-03-04T12:23:42.955514Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-03-04T12:25:47.602032Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 1978
2020-03-04T12:25:47.623263Z 0 [Warning] [MY-012360] [InnoDB]  Option innodb_dedicated_server is ignored for innodb_log_file_size because innodb_log_file_size=67108864 is specified explicitly.
2020-03-04T12:25:54.492113Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80018' to '80019' started.
2020-03-04T12:26:04.788132Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80018' to '80019' completed.
2020-03-04T12:26:24.417982Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-03-04T12:26:24.474922Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-03-04T12:26:24.566369Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060```
````

Comment: Please consider posting your complete my.cnf for analysis.  Do you have any GOOD reason for trying to run 8.0.19 that became GA 2020-01-13?  Most people wait 6 months before becoming the 'bug' finder and reporter with a version this new.

Comment: Ill try sending the my.cnf in a sec - thanks.  Believe it or not this was happening prior to upgrading to mysql 8.  it is more of a dev server and is not super critical - but this log issue is odd.

Comment: the comment feature isnt formatting well. link to the [my.cnf] (https://gist.github.com/sphen13/7f57c2adabfbc0ed741eaa871df51b52) @wilson-hauck

Comment: It looks like your innodb_log_file_size=64M is getting in the way of this being a 'dedicated server'.  Lead with # to disable the line.  Why are you using 'binlog_expire_logs_seconds=259200 seconds (72 hours)?  It appears you did upgrade to '80019' successfully and are ready for connections through port 33060.

Comment: i can comment out that line and see what happens. i had set the binlog expire at one point because the binlogs were just growing and growing and never purging - filling up the server. also - just remembered from before that it seems innodb_fast_shutdown is set to 1. should that not be the case? is that causing a dirty shutdown? thank you @wilson-hauck

Comment: Fast_shutdown should be 0 to avoid recovery during restart.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @StephenBoyle - After getting it going again, did "only one log file found" recur?

Comment: yes - i went through the suggestions above - have commented out innodb_log_file_size and now it creates a single ib_logfile0 that is 512M in size. Second one is still not there :/ @rick-james

Comment: MariaDB 10.2.4 (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12061) allows only 1.  I don't see anything saying that 8.0 did the same.